# Safari Cache size for iPhone 3.0

Tags: iphone, caching, safari

Various sites on the internet claims that Safari cache on iPhone 2.2 is 25k and 19 objects. Does anyone know what is the cache size for Safari/webview on iPhone 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... as far as i'm aware of, the cache size since version 2.2 is much larger.
specially if you use the client side storage or a cache manifest, you can store much more data.

how to store values clientside can be read here

[Apple developer Connection](https://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH1)

[PDF version](https://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/SafariJSDatabaseGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

> specially if you use the client side storage or a cache manifest, you can store much more data

Client application storage is different than the Safari's own cache, to which the original poster was referring. We know that in 2.2, Safari can store 19 objects each up to 25K in size. What are the new numbers for 3.0+?  The posted link/pdf doesn't seem to have the answer.