# iphone: caching and updating xml fields

Tags: iphone, oop

Thanks for your help. Here I have another question. I get the data through XMLParsing, now I want to store it in iphone's cache, and the XML Fields are updates every 12 hours.how can i check that XML Fields are change or not? and how can I store the data in iphone's cache memory so that evry it does not has to interact with web. Can anybody please help me???

Comment: Ambiguous title and tags. Please correct that so you have a better chance of getting help.

Answer (score 0):

i just answered them on another post.
[Safari Cache size for iPhone 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805891/safari-cache-size-for-iphone-3-0/806010#806010)

how to store values clientside can be read here

[Apple developer Connection](https://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH1)

[PDF version](https://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/SafariJSDatabaseGuide.pdf)