# Caching in HTML5

Tags: caching, html

1. How to enable mobile web caching in HTML5?
2. is it possible to store dynamic data in mobile device using HTML5?
3. What type of data's can be stored and max size?

please let me know if you come across tutorial.

Thanks in advance,

sri

Comment: Do you mean caching?

Comment: What browsers are you targeting?

Comment: http://playground.html5rocks.com/#localstorage

Answer (score 1):

You should use [localstorage](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/). The limit on the iPhone is 5 or 10 MB according to this question:
[Limit of localstorage on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone)

Comment: Yes. it is caching. plz correct me if my language is not good.
am targeting all browsers instead of any single browser.