# iOS storage for WebApp

Tags: ios, storage

is it possible to save files on the device from a WebApp? If it is so, which size does it have?

So hope that there is help for me.

Thanx 
newone

Answer (score 0):

Nope, unless the user does it, such as the *Save Image* option.

Comment: @newone: You can store to `localStorage` etc, but I doubt it's what you want.

Comment: ok and when I use it. Which limit size does the localStorage have?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari supports [a number of offline storage mechanisms](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH1-DontLinkElementID_20), but none for files per se.

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage or HTML5 SQL.

The limit for iPhone is 5MB with option to expand 5MB per time, if you are using HTML5 SQL. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone#2679277).). So you are a bit constrained.

See the Safari documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html).