# How to implement an app wide in-memory cache in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, singleton, global-variables

Is there a way to implement an app-wide in-memory cache for a HTML5 web application?

Is there a HTML5 feature to have in-memory cache of data? I'm not talking about the browser cache which merely stores server responses. I need caching of more efficient objects.

One possibility I can think of is to implement a global singleton JavaScript object that will be created once for the lifetime of the app, so that it can handle caching and retrieving data. If this is the only way, how can such a singleton object be created?

Comment: What's wrong with [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage)?

Comment: A lot of HTML5 web applications are designed to be just one page that's updated with content as the application proceeds.

Comment: Is `localStorage` saved on the disk or is it in-memory? Does it work for total data size of say 1 MB for mobile browsers? I couldn't find this information in the Mozilla link.

Comment: Here's a question and answer regarding the size limit of `localStorage` on iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone

Comment: For *much* more infornmation regarding `localStorage`, [read this](http://www.webdirections.org/blog/localstorage-perhaps-not-so-harmful/).

Comment: Thanks Joseph. But from the [link](http://www.webdirections.org/blog/localstorage-perhaps-not-so-harmful/) you sent, `localStorage` seems very slow and not fit for purpose of a robust cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a really simply singleton without too much enforcement. It could be done on a really protected way, where the Cache constructor isn't really accessible to the outer world, tell me if interested.

```
function Cache() {
     if ("instance" in arguments.callee)
       throw "new instance is not desired";
    var simpleCache = {};

     this.set = function(key, data) {
        simpleCache[key] = data;
     };

     this.get = function(key) {
       return simpleCache[key];
     };  
};

Object.defineProperty(Cache, "instance", { value: new Cache(), writable: false });
```

Now you call as you'd expect:

```
Cache.instance.set("key1", { a: "field1Value", b:12 });
Cache.instance.set("key2", new XMLHttpReuquest());
```