# React JS not opening in apple browsers

Tags: ios, reactjs

I have a website created in react js, when I try to open it on windows or android the loading happens normally.
But on IOS devices it doesn't load anything from the site.
I tried to use https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js in my index but I still couldn't.
PS: I don't have a mac to debug, tests only on an iphone version 15, I didn't find the iphone ios console to see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, first step was to update the browserslist.
Second it was seen that the application was with storage in localStorage above what safari was handling, thus causing the error.
Removed localStorage.
Link:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist
Link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone#:~:text=Mobile%20Safari%20on%20the%20iPhone,limit%2C%20afaik%2C%20on%20localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone#:%7E:text=Mobile%20Safari%20on%20the%20iPhone,limit%2C%20afaik%2C%20on%20localStorage).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue myself at the moment. What was the change you made to your browserslist? Is there a way for me to view what versions of React are broken with certain versions of iOS browsers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually debug the site, you'll need a Macbook or computer running OSX and an iPhone to connect to it with a USB cable.

I'd look for a project on GitHub that's mobile-specific and obviously supports Safari and iPhone. Preferably, run the project yourself and verify it works on an iPhone. Then compare the source of that project to yours and adjust yours to be similar.

Or spin up a very barebones React project and get it to load on an iPhone, then add the features of your project piece by piece, checking on the iPhone after each step, until you either find what breaks Safari on the iPhone or it just magically works.